# How can i align absolute-positioning images in center?

Tags: html, css, css-position

i have a div with **position:relative**.
Inside that div i have placed images with **position:absolute** because i'm going to have a slideshow with fadeIn and Fade out and the images have to be positioned absolute.

I would like to **align** the absolute-positioning images in the center
of their parent div. Can this be done??
Cause in the css part i have already defined all the images to be

```
left:0px;
```

My coding is as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">

div img{

    border:1px solid blue;
    position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    top:0px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div style="border:2px solid red;position:relative;width:500px;height:300px;">

    <img src="01.JPG" width="403" height="300"/>    
    <img src="02.JPG" width="403" height="300"/>
    <img src="03.jpg" width="170" height="290"/> <!-- this is a portrait,BIG problem         here!!! --> <!-- The image is positioned left -->
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Thanks, in advance!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set:

```
left:50%; margin-left:-<image width/2>px
```

So in this case, for the third image:

```
left:50%; margin-left:-85px
```

**See:** http://jsbin.com/ufiqum

Comment: Thanks for the code,so i have to use jquery in order to take the .width() of the Image and then calculate the left positioning, right? Or is there any other way to implement it?How did you calculate that in your coding??

Comment: I divided the image width by 2. I see that wasn't entirely clear so I've updated my answer. Yes, you'll need JavaScript/jQuery to calculate this.

Answer (score 4):

You need to calculate the position yourself.

left = center position - 1/2 of image width

Comment: Thanks for your answer, how can i get the value of the "center position"??

Comment: center = 1/2 of the width of the containing element.